# How do I change which files VS Code identifies as tests?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using the **Default Dark+** theme, VS Code shows "regular" `.js` files with a yellow **js** icon, and files ending in `.test.js` with an orange icon.

This is useful and I'd like to have files ending in `.tests.js` to be identified as test files too.

Is there a way to configure VS Code so it identifies both patterns?

Comment: these icons are determined by the File Icon Theme, you can create an issue at the extension